# Exponentials, Indeterminations and Limits (why is this proof wrong?)

Tags: calculus, limits, logic

A friend of mine showed me this. While I know that the proof is wrong, I can't understand what is failing exactly.

Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be two expressions that as $x\to0$ also tend to $0$.

$$\lim_{x\to0}(a(x)/b(x))\mbox{ is }0/0$$ (assume that it is an indeterminate form)

$$a(x)/b(x) = \ln(\exp(a(x))) / b(x) = (1/b(x)) \cdot \ln(\exp(a(x))) = Ln((\exp(a(x))^{1/b(x)})$$

Making $x\to0$, we get $\ln(\exp(0)^∞)) = \ln(1^∞) = \ln(1) = 0$

This is obviously not true, as $\sin x / x$, for instance, contradicts this.

What I would like to know is what step is wrong in this conjecture; what makes this whole thing fail?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fault in the process:
$$\boxed{\ln(\exp(0)^∞)) = \ln(1^∞)\boxed{\neq}\ln(1) = 0}$$
The reason is that $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: I know about L'Hopital's rule. This wasn't to solve any particular limit, simply this was a "proof" that any limit starting off with those assumptions would yield 0, which is obviously not true. The question is not about solving a limit, just to understand why this proof is wrong.

Comment: I know it's an indeterminate form...that's the point of this "conjecture", to try to prove that you can simplify it to yield 0.

What I would like to hear is "there is this error of thought in this assumption/step in the proof"? Because I can't seem to find it, but it must be there.

Comment: I understand that L'Hopital's rule disproves this, but my question is simply: Why is this proof in particular wrong? What is wrong with it? I never assumed that a(x)/b(x) -> 0, that was what it was trying to prove, actually.

Comment: @latrol I changed the answer.

Comment: ahhh yes, that's why. Idk how I missed that, I think it was because before I had a typo there where it was 1/infinity. Alright! that's solved then

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with a false premise, which can then lead you anywhere.  Maybe you can say that $a(x)/b(x) $ itself is of the form $0/0$, but you cannot conclude that this passes to the limit; for one thing, your ratio is not continuous at $0$ .Just because $a(x), b(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $x \rightarrow 0 $ does not imply that the limit of the ratio $a(x)/b(x) \rightarrow 0 $ is an indeterminate $0/0$; take, e.g., $a(x)=sinx, b(x)=x $; then the limit as $ x \rightarrow 0 $ is 1 , not indeterminate. Besides, in your argument, your expression is not continuous at 0, so you cannot introduce the limit into the expression.

Comment: That's true, but does the fault lie there? For example, if I were to use sinx/x , which is an indeterminate form 0/0, and then follow this "conjecture", where does it fail?

Comment: @latrol: you cannot introduce limits in the expression because $1/b(x) $ is not continuous at $0$; you can only guarantee that $lim _{x_n \rightarrow x_0} f(x_n)=f(x_0)$ when $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: besides, the limit $a(x)/b(x)$ is not equal to $0/0$ ; maybe you can say $a(x)/b(x)$ is of the form $0/0$ ; if you use $lim_{x\rightarrow 0} a(x)/b(x)= 0/0$, then this is false, and you are starting with a false premise.

Comment: Yeah, we can assume instead that a(x)/b(x) is an indeterminate form to begin with (like sinx/x))

Comment: I am not sure if that's the problem. at 0, 1/x explodes to plus or minus infinity, I am not attributing any particular value to it. In fact, in the conjecture it assumes that it can be either one.

Comment: But you are introducing the limit inside of the expression, you are saying that $ lim _{ x \rightarrow 0 } ln(a(x)^{1/b(x)})=ln a(lim_x \rightarrow 0 )^{1/b(lim_{x \rightarrow 0 }$ You can do this in values of $x$ where  $a(x)^{1/b(x)}$ is continuous, otherwise what allows you to interchange the limits?

Comment: ah, yes. I think that's it, wasn't realizing I was "assuming" that step in taking the limit like that, that should be the problem there. Thanks.

Comment: Sure; sorry for my poor Latex; I got tired after trying to reedit like 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

When $x \to 0$, we get $\ln (\exp(0)^\infty)$, not $\ln (\exp(0)^{1/\infty})$.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo. My question remains, though.

Comment: @latrol This is where you begin getting wrong.